# How to get ALL likes for a given media-id

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to iterate over the user ID of each like for a given {media_id}

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/likes?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

is returning something like this (a data array of approx 300 likes)

```
{
    "data": [{
        "username": "jack",
        "first_name": "Jack",
        "last_name": "Dorsey",
        "type": "user",
        "id": "66"
    },
    {
        "username": "sammyjack",
        "first_name": "Sammy",
        "last_name": "Jack",
        "type": "user",
        "id": "29648"
    }]
}
```

The problem is that it does not return **ALL** the likes, or any pagination feature.

Is there any workaround to get **ALL likes** for a given {media_ID}?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using the correct API endpoint to get media likes, however this endpoint has a limitation. It only returns a maximum of 100-120 likes per media with no pagination.

Unfortunately there is no workaround!

The same limitation applies for the comments endpoint.

Comment: Is this still the case that there is no pagination? The doc only says **Get a list of users who have liked this media.**  Where does it state this maximum of 120? I only have 3 test users in my sandbox app so I can't find out yet.

Answer (score 3):

Check [this](https://github.com/LevPasha/Instagram-API-python) Python library out.

Then you can use this sample code I made; however, It will only get 1000 of the most recent likes.

```
from InstagramAPI import InstagramAPI

likes_list = []

def get_likes_list(username):

    API.searchUsername(username) #Gets most recent post from user
    info = API.LastJson
    username_id = info['user']['pk']
    user_posts = API.getUserFeed(username_id)
    info = API.LastJson
    media_id = info['items'][0]['id']

    API.getMediaLikers(media_id)
    f = API.LastJson['users']
    for x in f:
        likes_list.append(x['username'])

get_likes_list("tailopez")
print(likes_list)
```